# Return Type from User Control of VS Environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2015

I got a annoying message from Visual Studio 2015, when I try to get some Instance from ASCX controls.  Can anybody give me suggestions?

Step 1. Create a WebForm Project, .NET 4.6.

Step 2. Build Car.cs in App_Code Folder.

```
namespace MyTest
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

step 3. Build People.ascx in root path.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    private MyTest.Car _Car = new MyTest.Car();
    public MyTest.Car oCar
    {
        get { return _Car; }
    }
    public string carName
    {
        set
        {
            _Car.name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _Car.name;
        }
    }
    public string peopleName { set; get; }
    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ascxMsg.Text = peopleName + " driving " + carName;
    }
</script>
<asp:Literal ID="ascxMsg" runat="server" />
```

Step 4. Build WebForm1.aspx in root path.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Src="People.ascx" TagPrefix="foo" TagName="boo" %>

<script runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        testing.peopleName = "John";
        testing.carName = "BMW";

        MyTest.Car oTempCar = testing.oCar;
        msg.Text = oTempCar.name;
    }

</script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <foo:boo id="testing" runat="server" /><br />
            <asp:literal id="msg" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All works very perfectly, the browser shows:

```
John driving BMW
BMW
```

**But... some annoying message continuing displayed on my VS 2015, the red underline shows: **

```
The type 'Car' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'App_Code.brabra...'.
```

[image: How to remove the Red underline?]

P.S The codes are just demostrating the problems for error messages. Please don't take it seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving Car.cs to a standalone class library or converting to web application project can avoid the error.  I guess it's a bug of VS2015 that it doesn't reference compiled App_Code binary correctly in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your uc properties should have string type. Use carName instead of Car.

Comment: that is not my question point. just a code sample don't take it seriously.